# Dapper one to many losing Id in the many

Tags: dapper

Given the following two entities

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Orders = new List<Orders>();
    }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public List<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Orders
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string OrderDescription { get; set; }
}
```

And the following code

```
string sql = @"
select c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName, o.OrderId as OrderId, o.CustomerId, o.Quantity, o.OrderDescription 
from Customer c 
join Orders o on c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId";

var customers = new List<Customer>();
Customer currentCustomer = null;
var c = connection.Query<Customer, Orders, Customer>(
    sql, (customer, order) => {
        if (currentCustomer == null || currentCustomer.CustomerId != customer.CustomerId) 
        {
            customers.Add(customer);
            currentCustomer = customer;
        }
        currentCustomer.Orders.Add(order);
        return currentCustomer;
    }, splitOn: "CustomerId, OrderId");
```

When I inspect customers the OrderId is always 0. As in customers.Orders[0].OrderId is zero, for all of them. Now I suppose it is me doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what. The strange SQL you see above is my attempts to try and force the OrderId to work.

Comment: Turns out I didn't understand or use SpliutOn correctly. It's my understanding now that SplitOn is for the Id's other than the "main" table. So all I had to do was change it to splitOn: "OrderId" and all was solved.

I had assumed that splitOn was for the joins.

Comment: I was just about to add an answer to that effect. Maybe you should add that as an answer?